# Excel SEARCH failure on identical strings containing "~"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula reducing to

```
=SEARCH("Exchange~server","Exchange~server")
```

Excel errors on this with "A value used in this formula is of the wrong data type". I know my data can be fixed with

```
=SEARCH(SUBSTITUTE("Exchange~server","~","-"),SUBSTITUTE("Exchange~server","~","-"))
```

But, what does excel do to make the first option not work?

Edit: updating title to reflect true issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

```
=FIND("Exchange~server","Exchange~server")
```

works returning a value of `1`

However, when you use `SEARCH`, wild card characters are allowed in `Find_text`.  The **rules** for that include one that states that a `tilde-x` eg (`~s`) will search for only the `s`.  This is generally used to be able to return the literal wild-card characters `*` and `?`.  But it will be true for any character following the tilde.

So your `find_text` argument reduces to `"Exchangeserver"` which, of course, cannot be found if you are searching `"Exchange~server"` with the literal tilde.

To do that, you must change `find_text` to `"Exchange~~server"` (double tilde `~~`).  The `~~` will reduce to the literal `~`.

i.e:  `=SEARCH("Exchange~~server","Exchange~server")`